Find a good (cylinder) embeddings of cylinder graphs
I asked this question before, and now I want the stack prim (or cylinder) to resemble a circular ladder (embedded into a cylindrical barrel). I made some slight modifications to the cvgmt's code, and it seems to work, but I have to say it looks quite ugly. The main issue is that some points visually overlap.
Clear[ptss];
n = 8;
k = 4;
ptss = Table[CirclePoints[{0, 3*i}, 3, n], {i, 1, k}];
g = Graph[{UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1, 1] & /@ ptss, 
    UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ Transpose@ptss} // 
   Flatten, VertexCoordinates -> Flatten[ptss, 1]]


Perhaps drawing it as shown in the following figure  from the paper would be a better approach.


You can use 3D coordinates in VertexCoordinates. Then Graph will display a 3D graph which you can rotate freely.
Clear[ptss];
n = 8;
k = 4;
(* ptss is modified to represent 3d coordinates *)
ptss = Table[
   Append[#, i] & /@ CirclePoints[{0, 3}, 3, n], {i, 1, k}];
g = Graph[{UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1, 1] & /@ ptss, 
    UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ Transpose@ptss} // 
   Flatten, VertexCoordinates -> Flatten[ptss, 1]]


